# Apple Script won't display line breaks

Tags: dialog, applescript, line-breaks, display

Making a small script to connect me to the console on some cisco equipment via  a usb to serial connection in terminal.

However I am finding it impossible to put line breaks or returns in between the text and Variables (like using  <br> in HTML).
So in the display dialog line all the text comes out all mashed together.

I have tried using \n , \ \n,  changing the preferences to Formatting > escape tabs and line Breaks in strings > Checked.

So any help would be much appreciated.

```
set theFind to "ls /dev/tty.*"
set theResult to do shell script theFind

set theConnection to text returned of (display dialog "Serial interface to availble:" & theResult & "Interface to use:" default answer "/dev/tty.usbserial")

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 1
        keystroke "screen " & theConnection & " 9600"
        keystroke return
        beep
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript doesn't use linefeeds as line breaks (as unix generally does), it uses carriage returns. You can translate them with `tr '\n' '\r'` (suitably escaped, of course). Also, you'll need to manually add returns before & after the included output; for some bizarre reason, AppleScript uses `\n` for that instead of `\r`. Here's the net result:

```
set theFind to "ls /dev/tty.* | tr '\\n' '\\r'"
set theResult to do shell script theFind

set theConnection to text returned of (display dialog "Serial interface to availble:\n" & theResult & "\nInterface to use:" default answer "/dev/tty.usbserial")

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 1
        keystroke "screen " & theConnection & " 9600"
        keystroke return
        beep
    end tell
end tell
```